# Website and iphone app updating to the same database

Tags: iphone, sql, database, xhtml

I am a novice at making websites but i need some help concerning my project. I have done some research and also some analysis on how to create websites but i have a problem. I want to create a social photo sharing website in which users can upload photos from their iphones unto the website via an app. I am considering using a database engine which can be used for both app and the website or should i just use different databases for both sites.I need suggestions how to go about this problem.

Tolu

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate database. Your website should just be a frontend to something like a LAMP server (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP). You're going to need to develop your own private database API to insert and retrieve items.

In your app you'll probably be making use of NSURLConnection to send asynchronus requests to your PHP api.  You should look into some of the open JSON frameworks to encode and decode responses.

Your question is very broad in scope and it should be broken down into several.  Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the reply. My question is broad but i will try to simpify it now. My project is a photo sharing website in which users upload pictures on the website either from their iphones or the website. I was planning to use SQLite as a database to sort the data which includes user details,photo albums and photos, user comments and other forms of user data.

Comment: I have never developed an iphone application before so the concept of web services looks like a good way to go as i dont want to store data on the iphone. Its just going to be selecting a photo from the Photo app on the iphone and uploading it unto the website unto the MySql database.The website is just going to be the main store for data and the iphone just acts as an extention and login to the website with upload features and user feeds from friends and people who have uploaded pictures and have decided to share their images publicly.

Answer (score 0):

What @Justin Amberson said is true. You may check out this tutorial to give you an idea how to build it for your app. I hope that helps you. http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app